# Traffic Allocation UI

Tags: forms, sliders

I am working on a UI for an A/B testing web-app. One of the features is traffic allocation, where you can set the percentage of the visitors that will see every variation of the test. For example, 20% will see version A, 30% will see version 2 and 50% - version C.
What are good example of tackling this feature? I want people to easily reach exactly 100% and not think as less as possible if the value they gave each variation is getting them exactly to 100%...

Comment: The simpliest way is to use two inputs for A and B versions and auto-calculated non-editable field for C version. Standard HTML inputs and a little javascript.

Comment: Agreed with Alexey. apart from you can also have some presets (20-20-60, 30-30-40 etc...)

Answer (score 1):

I like Alexey's solution.

Alternatively to humble bundle sliders, you can implement multiple handlers in same slider.

Some sample
http://jsfiddle.net/q5WEe/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a series of sliders, where moving one automatically adjusts the others so that they add up to a total of 100%. This has been implemented well on the [Humble Bundle donation page](https://www.humblebundle.com/#contribute):

[image: Humble Bundle donation allocation sliders]